# align equations with curly bracket

Tags: align, alignment, brackets

**I 'm trying to align "=", but I have problem with the curly brackets.**

I tried this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    
% amsmath
\begin{align*}
    \boldsymbol{r}'(s)&=\boldsymbol{v}(s)\Leftrightarrow \\
    x'(s)\boldsymbol{e_1}+y'(s)\boldsymbol{e_2}+u'(s)\boldsymbol{e_3}&=\left( x(s),-y(s),u(s)\right) \Leftrightarrow\\ \begin{cases}
        \dfrac{\strut d x}{\strut d s}=x(s)\\
        \dfrac{\strut d y}{\strut d s}=-y(s)\\
        \dfrac{\strut d u}{\strut d s}=u(s)
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

% mathtools
\[\begin{aligned}
    \boldsymbol{r}'(s)&=\boldsymbol{v}(s)\Leftrightarrow \\
    x'(s)\boldsymbol{e_1}+y'(s)\boldsymbol{e_2}+u'(s)\boldsymbol{e_3}&=\left( x(s),-y(s),u(s)\right) \Leftrightarrow\\ \begin{dcases}
        \dfrac{\strut d x}{\strut d s}&=x(s)\\
        \dfrac{\strut d y}{\strut d s}&=-y(s)\\
        \dfrac{\strut d u}{\strut d s}&=u(s)
    \end{dcases}
\end{aligned}\]
\end{document}
```

But, as you can see, the "="s inside the curly bracket do not align with the others.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlength\dxds
\begin{document}
\settowidth\dxds{$\dfrac{\strut d x}{\strut d s} =$}
\[
    \begin{aligned}
        \boldsymbol{r}'(s)
            &= \boldsymbol{v}(s)\Leftrightarrow \\
        x'(s)\boldsymbol{e_1}+y'(s)\boldsymbol{e_2}+u'(s)\boldsymbol{e_3}
            &= \left( x(s),-y(s),u(s)\right) \Leftrightarrow\\
        & \hspace{-\dxds}\left\{\begin{aligned}
            \dfrac{\strut d x}{\strut d s}&=x(s)\\
            \dfrac{\strut d y}{\strut d s}&=-y(s)\\
            \dfrac{\strut d u}{\strut d s}&=u(s)
        \end{aligned}\right.
    \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT. Instead of `dcases`, I have added a stretchable left curly bracket; note it needs to be closed by either its complementary part, either the right bracket or a hollow item `\right.`. Then, I moved the whole block to the right-hand side of `=` and use negative spacing.

The `\settowidth{<len>}{text or expression}` can measure how much space the expression takes and store it in a length name. Then this amount is used to move the whole block towards the left.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Problem solved! Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks. Just one remark I forgot to mention. `\leftX...\rightX` in regular math expressions is not the best approach, unless necessary, like the example above. It's better to substitute it with fixed sizes: `\biglX...\bigrX`, `\BiglX...\BigrX`, `\bigglX...\biggrX` and `\BigglX...\BiggrX`, where `X` can be any of the brackets or braces s.a. `( )`, `[ ]` or `\{ \}`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I 'll keep it in mind!